# Git commit without logging in

Tags: git, github

I'm using a machine that other people also use, so I don't want to input my Github credentials on it. Is there a way to commit changes in a code and use git pull from a private repository without logging in to Github in this machine ?

Comment: Feel free to setup ssh credentials with password, so that other people won't be able to use them to _push_ on your behalf (committing is a local operation.... no logging in involved.... unless you are talking about logging into the computer or resource where you are holding the local repo where you want to commmit).

Comment: thanks, I'll try the SSH aproach.

Comment: If all the machine users have access to this private repository, you could also consider deploy keys or deploy tokens with read and write permissions. But it's best to create a local username for each user, so that everyone can log in to the machine with their own username and have their own separated workspace. If all users use the same local username, it's not easy to manage ssh keys, git configs, personal credentials for different persons.